# Get average time taken to get from x% to y% (SQL)

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I'm using Athena that supports standard SQL queries and I need to get the average time it takes to get from 90+% to less than equal to 75%.

My data looks like this -

| Timestamp | Occupancy |
| --- | --- |
| 15:32 | 72% |
| 15:41 | 100% |
| 15:53 | 110% |
| 16:12 | 75% |

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: @sr49 I consider you should be clear about your question. Moreover, share a try you've done -with code included- in order to be easier to help you.